# JQuery text() only deletes HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a div containing tables and other elements. Is there a way to have $myElement.text() return tab delimited data like it does when I select a table and copy it to the clipboard? Right now all it does it just remove the tags and return the text, including loads of whitespace, which is rather useless.

```
var $email = $('#printPage').clone().appendTo(document.body);
$email.find('.noprint, .printview').remove();
$email.find('.addressPanel').css({'width':'49%', 'display':'inline-block'});
$email.find('.dynamicTable table').css({'width':'100%'});
var html = $email.html().replace(/<!--.*?-->/g, '');
var text = $email.text(); //this gives me a huge amount of whitespace
```

Comment: Can we get a JSFiddle code to better understand your problem please?

Comment: Neither `.text()` nor `.html()` will do what you want. You'll have to write your own code to traverse the table rows to build up a tab-delimited representation of each one.

Comment: have you tried .innerHTML?

Comment: Yes, it did the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.fn.getDelimitedText = function(){
    var str = '';
    $(this).find('tr').each(function(trIdx,tr){
        $(tr).find('td').each(function(tdIdx, td){
            if(tdIdx > 0){
                str += '\t';
            }
            str += $(td).text();
        });
        str += '\n';
    });
    return str;
};

var x = $('table').getDelimitedText();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/odh15d1s/2/

If you want to get all text within an element, you'll need to select all children of that element, but handle any tables slightly differently....

```
var str = '';
$('#foo > *').each(function(idx,el){
    if(el.tagName == 'TABLE'){
        str += $(el).getDelimitedText();
    } else {
        str += $(el).text();
    }
    str += '\n';
});

console.log(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/odh15d1s/4/

Comment: I should have thrown in that there is text around it. How would you do that?

Comment: There's text around _what_? This is going through each row in the table,  and getting the text within each cell?

Comment: Sorry, around the table.

Comment: @arlen That shouldn't affect this code. What trouble are you having? http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/odh15d1s/3/

Comment: I mean, it's actually several tables and divs and spans and what-not all mixed together, and I want to get the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer, but two other things come into play in my scenario, which I did not mention in my question. One is that the td contains elements which add whitespace to `.text()`. The other is that tables might be several  levels below the element we are calling `text()` on. If you wish to add in these scenarios as well, you are most welcome to.

Comment: @arlen [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/odh15d1s/6/) might help. `var els = $('#foo').find('table, > *:not("table")');`. It selects any tables within the div, and any immediate children (except tables).
Is the whitespace wanted or unwanted? You could use `$(this).text().trim()`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I finally came up with. One other thing that could be added would be to replace all HTML entities (`lt;&gt;`, etc.) with their equivelant values. It probably removes more line breaks that copying it straight from the screen would, but this does what I need it to.

```
$.fn.getDelimitedText = function(){
    var pres = [];
    var str = '';

    var checkSpace = /[ \r\n]+/gmi;
    var checkTags = /<(?!pre[ >])([^ \/>]*)(?:"[^"]*?"|[^">])*>/gmi;
    var checkLineBreaks = /\r?\n\r?\n/gmi;

    //Remove all comments immediately so they don't interfere.
    //Use alternation to catch line breaks also.
    var test = $(this).html().replace(/<!--(?:.|\n)*?-->/gmi, '');

    var count = 0;

    //replace all pre elements with a placeholder and store the contents 
    //in an array so they don't get modified.
    test.replace(/<(pre)(?: (?:"[^"]*?"|[^">])*)?>([\s\S]*?)<\/\1>/gmi, 
        function(match, tag, body, offset, input){
            pres.push(body);
            return '<pre ' + (pres.length - 1) + '/>';

        });


    function doTableRegex(outer, index){
        var lastPosition = 0;
        var table = {};

        //tbody, thead, tfoot. Don't assign the return to anything. We get that from the table var.
        outer.replace(/<(tbody|thead|tfoot)(?: (?:"[^"]*"|[^">])*)?>([\s\S]*?)<\/\1>/gmi, function(match, tag, body){
            //replace td and th elements
            body = body.replace(/<(th|td)(?: (?:"[^"]*"|[^">])*)?>([\s\S]*?)<\/\1>/gmi, function(match, tag, body1){
                return body1.replace(checkTags, '').replace(checkSpace, ' ') + "\t";
            });
            //replace tr elements
            body = body.replace(/<(tr)(?: (?:"[^"]*"|[^">])*)?>([\s\S]*?)<\/\1>/gmi, function(match, tag, body1){
                return body1.replace(checkTags, '').replace(checkSpace, ' ') + "\r\n";
            });
            //Multiple tbody elements are allowed in a table.
            //We'll allow for multiples of everything.
            if(table[tag]) table[tag] += "\r\n" + body;
            else table[tag] = body;
            //return nothing.
            return '';
        });

        //put the table sections in the correct order.
        return (table.thead || "") + "\r\n" + (table.tbody || "") + "\r\n" + (table.tfoot || "") + "\r\n";
    }
    //Replace all tables
    return test.replace(/<(table)(?: (?:"[^"]*"|[^">])*)?>([\s\S]*?)<\/\1>/gmi, doTableRegex)
    //replace br & hr tags with line breaks
    .replace(/<br ?\/?>|<hr ?\/?>/g, "\r\n")
    //remove all tags besides pre tags
    .replace(checkTags, '')
    //empty all lines of spaces
    .replace(/^ +$/gmi, '')
    //remove all empty lines
    .replace(/(?:\r?\n){2,}/gmi, "\r\n")
    //replace all double ( and more ) spaces with single spaces.
    .replace(/ +/gmi, ' ')
    //Add the contents of pre elements back in.
    .replace(/<pre(?: (?:id="([^"])"|"[^"]*"|[^">])*)?>/gmi, function(match, id){
        return "\r\n" + pres[parseInt(id)] + "\r\n";
    });

};
```